# How can send and receive message between gcm with openfire?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I creating hybrid messenger app using ionic & openfire.

I need push service, so used phonegap-plugin-push.

And succeeded receive push notification from test push server using gcm.

I have questions.

1. How can send and receive message between gcm with openfire? Because I want make app <=> gcm <=> openfire.
2. Should I create plugin? or server?
3. Anybody know openfire gcm plugin? and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin it may help you

https://github.com/meisterfuu/Openfire-GCM.git

Comment: How to add it? Can't use cordova plugin add https://github.com/meisterfuu/Openfire-GCM.git. And If u know any example code about Openfire-GCM?

Comment: I did upload Openfire-GCM gcmh.jar to openfire admin console using upload plugin. But nothing happened. How to use the plugin from ionic?